# Extract glyphs and make a new font

Tags: fonts, font-face, web-fonts

I have a web font that i'm using but I only need 0123456789. Is there a way to extract glyphs from that font and generate a new font?

Comment: Of course, you would want to be sure you're not violating the EULA. Most foundries are not fond of people taking their outlines, modding, and producing a new font. I've had to do this on several occasions for internal use and have always been able to get agreement from the foundry to do so.

Answer (score 3):

There sure is! Just use http://icomoon.io. It's a free webfont creation tool that works with SVG packs, as well.

Answer (score 0):

[ Correcting my format to abide by protocol ... ]

If you've read my comment above and you're good to go ... here's the rest of the process I follow.

1. open the font in [one of FontLab's tools](http://www.fontlab.com/)
2. tweak to your heart's content
3. export your revised font in any format you choose